# problems with flutter dismissible widget

Tags: flutter, dart

everytime i try to dismiss an item, it dismisses one, but in the second one it says

"A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree.
Make sure to implement the onDismissed handler and to immediately remove the Dismissible widget from
the application once that handler has fired."

I tried to implement the widget "UniqueKey()" but it didn´t worked. What am i doing wrong?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    import 'package:shop/models/cart.dart';
    import 'package:shop/models/cart_item.dart';
    
    class CartItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      final CartItem cartItem;
      const CartItemWidget(this.cartItem);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Dismissible(
          key: ValueKey(cartItem.id),
          direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
          background: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 15,
              vertical: 4,
            ),
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.delete,
              size: 30,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          ),
          onDismissed: (_) {
            Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false)
                .removeProduct(cartItem.productId);
          },
          child: Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 15,
              vertical: 4,
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                      child: FittedBox(
                        child: Text(
                          cartItem.price.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: Text(cartItem.name),
                  subtitle: Text("Total: ${cartItem.price * cartItem.quantity}"),
                  trailing: Text("${cartItem.quantity}x")),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: You might need to be wrapping your CartItemWidget with Dismissible.  Can you post the code that uses your CartItemWidget?

Comment: @JohnWeidner, the code that you are seeing it's already from CartItemWidget, and it's already wrapped in a dismissible widget.

Comment: I was wanting to see the code where you use the CartItemWidget.  I'm thinking you should be trying to "dismiss" a cart item, not dismiss a delete icon.  So Dismissible's child should be your CartItemWidget.